# Scala Swing Caret Position

Tags: java, swing, scala

I am using scala.swing.TextArea and creating a text area like so :

```
val textArea = new TextArea() { ... }
```

I have a really hard time getting the caret position in (x,y) form.

By lots of googling I found out that in Java there is a very easy way to do it by writing :

```
Point point = jEditorPane.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition();
```

Is there a way to do it in Scala, by either using the Java JTextArea , without braking my code, or by using a native Scala method?

What I am using right now is textArea.caret.position.toString which seems to be very confusing as it returns just an Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have the corresponding javax.swing component at hand through the `peer` method. Some less used methods are not wrapped in Scala Swing, unfortunately. The `position` is *not* the magic-position (visual point) but the logical character position. So you could call

```
textArea.peer.getCaret.getMagicCaretPosition
```